# Is custom promise implementation in Node.js going to block the I/O?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, libuv

So I wrote this Node.js module that is responsible for maintaining and manipulating current presence of employees using the application (there are 100 employees using it tops at the point).
There are methods here and there that basically update presence, either modifying or toggling certain properties of objects that represent employees currently using the applicaiton.
The syntax of those methods is typically such as

```
someFunction() {
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>
  do something ...
  if no error resolve(invocation of logging indicating success of operation)
  if error reject(invocation of logging indicating failure of operation)
)}
```

Basically then in my express routes I have a chain of operations that have to happen based on user interaction with our front-end that typically look like an async/await or sometines then().then().catch(). This presence object's methods are called within those chains sometimes. My question is. Is whatever is done in those presence methods going to be delegated to worker threads and so be asynchronous and then put back onto the call stack from the event loop once it is done or will it just block the current stack like any synchronous code? Is there any way to make it truly asynchronous and non-blocking? C++ libuv add ons? Can you please help me with this theoretical question?

Comment: No, putting code in a `new Promise` executor callback won't make it run in an extra worker thread or something. You would explicitly have to do that on your own if you wanted to.

Comment: For toggling a few properties on a few hundred objects, you don't need any asynchrony. The overhead of any approach to parallelise this would be much slower than the synchronous code itself.